# NHibernate Mapping-by-Code

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

How to add a additional field in the database schema(SQL) from NHibernate mapping exported that not exist on entity?

I have:

```
Property(x => x.Name, "Name");
Property(x => x.Description, "Product");
```

and I want add to exported schema(SQL):

```
Property("Department"); (this property not exist in the entity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an [AuxilliaryDatabaseObject](http://www.ronaldrosier.net/Blog/2013/05/14/setting_a_sequence_as_a_default_value_through_nhibernate).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that Nhibernate is not going to handle this scenario.  Nhibernate can map to an existing database in a database first scenario or generate the schema in a domain first scenario.  Nhibernate only knows about the database objects that you tell it about in the mapping.  Since you've got extra fields on tables it sounds like you've got a database first scenario and should use something like database version software.

Comment: This field is updated by a sql function(and is not necessary in the entity). I can generate the SQL schema(script) to create the table but without the "Department" column.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is to map it readonly, generated in you mapping, but your don't want to map it at all.

Comment: I just asking if it was possible, As I do not find much documentation, but I'll do it like this, thanks Fran.